# Angularjs ng-if not working with ng-model

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-model, angular-ng-if

I am using angularjs to integrate my api.

I am facing problem with using `ng-if` inside textbox.

so below is my snippet of HTML code:

```
<input type="text" value="" data-ng-if="edit" ng-model="name">
<input type="text" value="" data-ng-if="!edit" ng-model="singleAppDetails.name">
```

Here **edit** variable is there in scope
that is in my controller i have declared it like this:

```
$scope.edit = false;
```

So if **edit is false** it should get bind with `ng-model="name"`
and if **edit is true** it should get bind with `ng-model="singleAppDetails.name"` 
But it is not binding it as expected.

Further I am using `$http.post` to post the data to server like below:

```
 $scope.addApp = function(){    
       $scope.apps = []; 
        $scope.apps.push({'name':$scope.name, 'domain':$scope.domain, 'appId':$scope.appId, 'secret':$scope.secret});
        // Writing it to the server
        //      
        var dataObj = {
                name : $scope.name,
                domain : $scope.domain,
                appId : $scope.appId,
                secret : $scope.secret
        };  
        var res = $http.post('http://192.168.1.30:8090/apps/', dataObj);
        res.success(function(data, status, headers, config) {
            $scope.message = data;
        });
        res.error(function(data, status, headers, config) {
            alert( "failure message: " + JSON.stringify({data: data}));
        });     
        // Making the fields empty
        //
       $scope.name='';
       $scope.domain='';
       $scope.appId = '';
       $scope.secret = '';
    };
```

But this always sends null data.

Comment: Try to wrap inside a ng-if inside a div and check

Comment: I don't see edit is set to true and false anywhere in you code

Comment: @Sajeetharan

<div ng-if="edit">
                        <input type="text" value="" ng-model="name">
                    </div>
                    <div ng-if="!edit">
                        <input type="text" value="" ng-model="singleAppDetails.name">
                    </div>

Comment: @Sajeetharan see my above comment. I tried this but did not worked.

Comment: can you create a plnker?

Comment: @mahendrakawde the problem might be you are doing CORS request..

Comment: @pankajparkar i have set edit to false in my controller.

Answer (score 2):

`ng-if` has its own scope. So the `name` attribute that is populated by the first input is in the ng-if scope instead of being in your controller scope.

The second input should work fine, provided that your controller initializes singleAppDetails to a non-null object:

```
$scope.singleAppDetails = {};
```

Rule of thumb: always have a dot in your ng-model. Always populate objects in the scope rather than the scope itself.

Answer (score 2):

`ng-if` is creating a child scope because that the input elements does not see the scope variable defined in the controller you have two ways to solve this problem

1. use an object reference
   ex : 

   `$scope.user = { name : "" }`

   inside the template

   `<input type="text" ng-model='user.name' />`
2. you can tell angular to look for the variable in parent scope instead child scope

   `<input type="text" ng-model='$parent.name' />`